# How to display a success alert with vuetify after successfully inserting data into database

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have created a webapp that contains input-fields, radio buttons etc. There's a Submit button at the bottom that inserts the data into a database AFTER validating (checking if all required fields contain data). If the validation isn't successful, it shows an error alert (with vuetify --> v-alert). Now, if it's successful the website quickly reloads but there is no success message showing.

Edit: Also, once the error alert pops up, it stays open and prevents you from submitting even if the validation was successful.

Code:

```
<template>
    <v-container v-if="this.$store.state.loggedIn">
        <panel title="Ereignisprotokoll">
            <!-- Input fields for the teacher -->
            <v-layout align-center justify-space-around row fill-height>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm5 text-left>
                        <h2> Lehrperson</h2>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                    <v-text-field label="Kürzel*" v-model="data['short_teacher']" :rules="[v => !!v || 'Kürzel wird benötigt']" required>
                    </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                    <v-text-field label="Vorname*" v-model="data['first_teacher']" :rules="[v => !!v || 'Vorname wird benötigt']" required>
                    </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                    <v-text-field label="Nachname*" v-model="data['last_teacher']" :rules="[v => !!v || 'Nachname wird benötigt']" required>
                    </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <!-- Input fields for the student -->
            <v-layout align-center justify-space-around row fill-height>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm5 text-left>
                        <h2> Lernender</h2>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                    <v-text-field label="Kürzel*" v-model="data['short_student']" :rules="[v => !!v || 'Kürzel wird benötigt']" required>
                    </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                    <v-text-field label="Vorname*" v-model="data['first_student']" :rules="[v => !!v || 'Vorname wird benötigt']" required>
                    </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                    <v-text-field label="Nachname*" v-model="data['last_student']" :rules="[v => !!v || 'Nachname wird benötigt']" required>
                    </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                    <v-select label="Klasse*" :items="['inf16','inf17','inf18','inf19','inf20']" v-model="data['Class_student']" :rules="[v => !!v || 'Klasse wird benötigt']" required>
                    </v-select>
                </v-flex>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                    <v-text-field label="E-Mail*" v-model="data['mail_student']" :rules="[
                                                        (v) => !!v || 'E-mail wird benötigt',
                                                        (v) => /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/.test(v) || 'E-mail nicht gültig'
                                                        ]" required>
                    </v-text-field>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <!-- Radio Buttons for the reason (Verfehlung) -->
            <v-layout align-center>
                <v-container grid-list-xs>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                        <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                            <v-flex xs12 sm5 text-left>
                                <h2>Verfehlung*</h2>
                            </v-flex>
                        </v-flex>
                    </v-flex>
                    <v-flex no-gutters>
                        <v-flex xs12>
                            <v-radio-group v-model="data['reason_id']" column :rules="[v => !!v || 'Grund für Verfehlung wird benötigt']">
                                <v-radio label="Unpünktlichkeit" value="Unpünktlichkeit"></v-radio>
                                <v-radio label="Abmeldung nicht gemäss Reglement" value="Abmeldung nicht gemäss Reglement"></v-radio>
                                <v-radio label="Unvollständige oder fehlende Aufgaben bzw. Arbeiten" value="Unvollständige oder fehlende Aufgaben bzw. Arbeiten"></v-radio>
                                <v-radio label="Fehlendes Schul- oder Arbeitsmaterial" value="Fehlendes Schul- oder Arbeitsmaterial"></v-radio>
                                <v-radio label="PC unterrichtsfremd eingesetzt" value="PC unterrichtsfremd eingesetzt"></v-radio>
                                <v-radio label="Verletzung IT-Richtlinien" value="Verletzung IT-Richtlinien"></v-radio>
                                <v-radio label="Wiederholte oder massive Störung" value="Wiederholte"></v-radio>
                                <v-radio label="Vorgaben zur Arbeitssicherheit nicht befolgt" value="Vorgaben zur Arbeitssicherheit nicht befolgt"></v-radio>
                                <v-radio label="Anderes, siehe Massnahmen/Bemerkungen" value="Anderes"></v-radio>                            </v-radio-group>
                        </v-flex>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-container>
            </v-layout>
            <!-- Textarea for the measure (Massnahme) and remarks (Bemerkungen) -->
            <v-layout align-center row fill-height>
                <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                    <v-flex xs12 sm5>
                        <v-flex xs12 sm5 text-left>
                            <h2>Massnahmen/Bemerkungen*</h2>
                        </v-flex>
                    </v-flex>
                </v-flex>
            </v-layout>
            <v-layout align-center row fill-height>
                <v-text-field label="Massnahmen und Bemerkungen" name="name" :counter="500" textarea :rules="[v => !!v || 'Grund für Verfehlung wird benötigt']" v-model="data['massnahmen']"></v-text-field>
            </v-layout>
            <!-- Checkbox if the teacher wants to have a meeting with the student and the head of department -->
            <v-layout align-center row fill-height>
                <v-checkbox label="Runder Tisch gewünscht" v-model="data['runderTisch']" value=""></v-checkbox>
            </v-layout>
            <!-- Checkbox for signing the form -->
            <v-layout align-center row fill-height>
                <v-checkbox label="Signieren* (Hiermit wird bestätigt, dass die Angaben dieses Formulars korrekt sind und mit dem betroffenen Lernenden besprochen wurden. Dies kann nicht rückgängig gemacht werden.)" v-model="data['signatur']" value="" :rules="[v => !!v || 'Ereignisprotokoll muss signiert werden']">
                </v-checkbox>
            </v-layout>
            <br>
            <!-- Submit button -->
            <div>
                <v-layout align-center row fill-height>
                    <p style="color: red">* Pflichtfelder</p>
                </v-layout>
                <!-- <div v-html="error" style="color: red"></div>   -->
                <v-alert 
                    v-if="error"
                    :value="error"
                    outlined
                    color="red"
                    type="error"
                    style="width:33%"
                    transition="slide-y-transition"
                    >
                    {{error}}
                </v-alert> 

                <v-alert
                    v-if="savingSuccessful = null"
                    :value="alert"
                    color="green"
                    type="success"
                    style="width:33%"
                    transition="slide-y-transition"
                    >
                    Das Ereignisprotokoll wurde erfolgreich erstellt.
                </v-alert>  
                  
                <v-btn dark style="background-color:#0382b5" class="darken-2" type="submit" @click="submit" v-if="!savingSuccessful">Bestätigen
                </v-btn>
            </div>
            <br>
            <!-- Info button and text -->
            <v-hover>
                <v-card-text class="pt-1" style="position: relative">
                    <v-expand-transition>
                        <div v-if="isOpen" style="height: 100%; position: relative">
                            <h3 class="text-sm-left">Wichtige Hinweise:</h3>
                            <p class="text-sm-left">
                                Mit dem vorliegenden Ereignisprotokoll wird festgehalten, dass die Lehrperson eine Handlung oder ein Verhalten festgestellt hat, das nicht den geltenden und kommunizierten Vorgaben und Erwartungen entspricht.
                                <p class="text-sm-left">
                                    Mit ihrer Unterschrift bestätigen beide Parteien, dass die Lehrperson der bzw. dem Lernendenden erläutert hat, aus welchen Gründen eine Handlung order ein Verhalten verfehlt ist und wie dies in Zukunft korrigiert werden soll.
                                </p>
                                <p class="text-sm-left">
                                    Fünf Ereignisprotokolle führen zu einer gelben Karte (PL2107VA:LE-Disziplmassnahmen_I. Grobe Verfehlungen können direkt zu einer gelben Karte führen.Dazu zählen bspw.:
                                </p>
                                <p class="text-sm-left">
                                    Dazu zählen bspw.:
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Unentschuldigte Absenzen</li>
                                        <li>Nicht-Einhalten von persönlich unterzeichneten Weisungen (bspw. Lehrvertrag, IT-Weisugngen</li>
                                        <li>Beleidigung, Beschimpfung oder üble Nachrede gegenüer Lernenden, Mitarbeitenden und externen Partnern der .</li>
                                        <li>u.a.m.</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </p>
                        </div>
                    </v-expand-transition>
                    <v-btn color="#0382b5" @click="onClick()" dark absolute small fab right top>
                        <i class="material-icons">
                              info
                            </i>
                    </v-btn>
                </v-card-text>
            </v-hover>
        </panel>
    </v-container>
</template>
<script>
import Panel from '@/components/Panel'
import * as easings from 'vuetify/es5/util/easing-patterns'
import BackendRequests from '@/api/BackendRequests'
export default {
    // Defined local variables for this specific component 
    data() {
        return {

            vorname: this.$store.state.user.Vorname,
            nachname: this.$store.state.user.Nachname,
            klasse: this.$store.state.user.Klassenname,
            lernenderID: this.$store.state.user.ID_User,
            ereignisprotokolle: [],
            error: null,
            required: (value) => !!value || 'Ausfüllen',
            existingForm: [],
            isOpen: false,
            require_value: 1,
            alert: false,
            savingSuccessful: null,

            data: {
                reason_id: null,
                short_teacher: null,
                first_teacher: null,
                last_teacher: null,
                short_student: null,
                first_student: null,
                last_student: null,
                Class_student: null,
                mail_student: null,
                massnahmen: null,
                runderTisch: null,
                signatur: null,
            }
        }
    },
    methods: {
        // Send the form to the backend when all required fields have been completed
        async submit() {
            this.error = null
            Object.keys(this.data).forEach(key => {
                if(this.data[key]==null && key!='runderTisch'){
                    this.error = 'Bitte alle benötigten Felder ausfüllen.'
                }
            });
            this.data['teacher_id']=this.lernenderID;
            console.log(this.error)
            if(this.error==null){
                try {
                    let res = await BackendRequests.postForm(this.data)
                    this.$router.go()
                } catch (err) {
                    this.error = err.response.data.error;
                }
            }
            if(this.error !== err.response.data.error){
                this.savingSuccessful = true
            }
            window.setInterval(() => {
                this.alert = false;
                }, 3500)    
            },

        onClick() {
            if (this.isOpen === true) {
                this.isOpen = false
            } else {
                this.isOpen = true
            }
        },
        checkForm:function(e) {
            
        },
        hide_alert: function (event) {
        // `event` is the native DOM event
        window.setInterval(() => {
        this.alert = false;
         }, 3500)    
        
        },
  },
  
  mounted: function () {
    if(alert){
      this.hide_alert();
    }
  }
    }
    components: {
        Panel
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using v-model instead of value. Vuetify automatically closes it after some time. You can either set the timer or set it to permanent and manually handle the closing yourself